# twitter search api not returning results

Tags: php, twitter

i'm doing api calls from php backend like this:

```
$term     = "AT&T Park";        
$q        = '"'. urlencode($term) .'"';
$url      = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q={$q}&rpp=100";
$api_call = file_get_contents($url);
```

it's not returning anything, but same api call working just fine on my terminal.

here is a little screencast showing what's going on:

http://screencast.com/t/RnZsrwfGcc2q

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to urlencode the quotes too.

change your code to the following

```
$term     = '"AT&T Park"';
$q        = urlencode($term);
$url      = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q={$q}&rpp=100";
$api_call = file_get_contents($url);
```

and it should work

Comment: this doesn't work properly, it encodes quotes well, but ampersand is funny so i did `$term     = '%22'.urlencode("AT&T Park").'%22';` then it worked. I'm going to mark this as an answer, hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL in your PHP file.  This may work.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Comment: Sorry about that, it was worth a shot.  =(